# Django duplicates objects after reverse ordering

Tags: django

I'm running into a problem with requests in Django. I have a simple model with several fields include DateTimeField 'event_date':

```
class Event (models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=default_event_date)
  publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=default_publish_date)
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.event_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') + '-' + self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In a view.py I make a request and return objects from this model:

```
return Event.objects.filter(publish_date__lte=currentTime).order_by('-event_date')
```

And sometimes (I can't see a system) response looks like this:

- Object5 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 23:15, event_date = 2020/06/03 23:15)
- Object1 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object3 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object2 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object1 (for the second time and where is Object4?)

Interesting, if I change ordering to .order_by('event_date') - straight, not reverse, everything is ok:

- Object1 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object2 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object3 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object4 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 21:30, event_date = 2020/06/03 21:30)
- Object5 (pub_date = 2020/06/01 23:15, event_date = 2020/06/03 23:15)

What is it? Could this be due to the fact that several objects have the same value of 'event_date' field and 'publish_date' field?

Comment: show your models.py code

Comment: Are you sure `Object 1` the first time is not just `Object 4`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've changed publish_date in Object4 just for 1 minute and everything is working now. When I changed it back - everything is ok anyway. I can't understand what it was.

Answer (score 1):

The duplication is due to the underlying SQL code that is generated and the joins that are occurring.

The way to de-dup' it is to use `.distinct()`

```
return (Event.objects
    .filter(publish_date__lte=currentTime)
    .order_by('-event_date')
    .distinct()
)
```

Comment: I think that it works is coincidence. What joins are you talking about? `str(UserProfile.objects.filter(dob__lte='1980-01-01').only('dob').order_by('-dob').query)
'SELECT "core_userprofile"."id", "core_userprofile"."dob" FROM "core_userprofile" WHERE "core_userprofile"."dob" <= 1980-01-01 ORDER BY "core_userprofile"."dob" DESC'`

Comment: That `distinct()` de-duplicates is a fact.  That's how `select distinct` works.  The joins is just a guess.  His question probably omits something else in his code base that includes a join and the join on another table duplicates the `Event` row in the results.